# Pan-frying marinated meat without making a huge mess?

Tags: frying, pan, marinade, frying-pan

I love marinated meat, I love the extra flavor that the marinade adds to it. However, I don't always have the option to BBQ it, so sometimes I have to use a frying pan.

However, this always creates a huge, huge mess. The oil in the pan seems to not like the marinade, it immediately starts to crackle and boil, spilling hot oil everywhere.

I thought that I didn't use enough oil, so today I used a bit more, but that made it even worse. Using less oil seems to make it hard to actually get good meat, that is meat that is NOT a lump of coal on the outside and raw inside.

So I thought I'd ask for advice here :)

Comment: Oil does not like water. That is universally true. Hot oil *really* doesn't like water - consider the temperature and the boiling point.

Comment: Another option is to use a broiler if you have one (instead of stovetop in the frying pan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the issue is the hot oil and water interacting. You need to reduce or eliminate one in order to prevent the splatter or find a way to mitigate the damage.

Remember the basics - allow the meat to warm up to room temperature before cooking and pat it dry before you begin. That should allow you to use less oil without it turning into a charred lump with a raw center. You can use a lid or a screen to prevent splatter (you might need to adjust cooking time with a lid that will trap more heat).

Comment: Putting it between some kitchen towel for a few minutes indeed did do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pat it dry first.  The marinade has already worked it's magic on the meat.